# Storing and Searching Large Data Set

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to programming in C++ and I'm trying to create a data set that just has two values: an ID number and a string. There will be about 100,000 pairs of these. I'm just not sure what data structure would best suit my needs.

The data set has the following requirements:

-the ID number corresponding to a string is 6 digits (so 000000 to 999999)

-not all ID values between 000000 and 999999 will be used

-the user will not have permission to modify the data set

-I wish to search by ID or words in the String and return to the user ID and String

-speed of searching is important

So basically I'm wondering what I should be using (vector, list, array, SQL database, etc) to construct this data set and quickly search it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the ID number corresponding to a string is 6 digits (so 000000 to
>   999999)

Good, use an `int`, or more precisely `int32_t` for the ID

> -not all ID values between 000000 and 999999 will be used

Not a problem...

> -the user will not have permission to modify the data set

Encapsulate your data within a class and you are good to go

> -I wish to search by ID or words in the String and return to the user ID and String

Good, use [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

> -speed of searching is important

I know, that's why you are using C++... :-)

You may also want to check [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) : SQLite, can also function as an in-memory database.

Answer (score 0):

use std::map

```
void main()
{
   std::map<string /*id*/, string> m;
   m["000000"] = "any string you want";
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to search both the id and the string.  maps only search by the key.

Answer (score 0):

Vector & list are worst to use if you don't sort them, you don't want loop through all.
I suggest you use map, even tho building the entire map might take longer (nlogn). I still recommend it, since the runtime for searching is log(n) which is pretty fast!

> "speed of searching is important"

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like a class which contains a vector of your id/string pairs, an unordered_map which maps id to an iterator or reference into that vector, and an unordered_map which maps a string to an iterator or reference into that vector. Then, two search functions in the class which look up the id/string pair based on the id or a string.

Comment: What about duplicated strings? Map key must be unique.

Comment: std::unordered_multimap

Answer (score -1):

You have couple of options.

1. Use database, MySQL, SQLite etc. Performance depends on the database you use.
2. Or, if you want to do it in C++ code, you can use vectors. One vector for the key, another is for the string. You also need to map the related index between 2 vectors.

Sort both vectors after add a new item. Remember to update the map of related index

Then use binary search to find either key, or value. It shall be fast enough.

Comment: There are much better standard data structures.

Comment: @RobK Name some please?

Comment: std::unordered_map